# Creating a surface of triangles from a set of 2D points

Tags: set, geometry

I have a set of points and I need to convert the set to (non-overlapping) triangles (or a big polygon if equivalent)...

The application: I have a list of locations (latitude,longitude) from a country, and I need to find if a given point is inside the counrty or not...

```
X         X                   *---------*                       *---------*
                              | \     / | \                     |           \
                              |   \ /   |   \                   |             \
     X         x      =>      |    *    |    *      = or =>     |              *
                              |   / \   |   /                   |             /
                              | /     \ | /                     |           /
X         X                   *---------*                       *---------*
```

Is there an easy way or do I need a PhD to code it?

Or with a huge polygon?  I found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Thx,
JD

Comment: Nah, a Bachelor's degree should suffice :P

Answer (score 3):

It would actually be easier to calculate the final polygon than constructing the polygon from triangles.

What you're looking for is the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a set of points. Many [different algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Planar_case) exist to do this.

In my algorithms class, we studied the [gift-wrapping algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) (a.k.a.: The Jarvis March). It's fairly simple, but faster solutions exist.

If you want to construct the full [polygon mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh), you would have to run a [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_%28advanced_geometry%29) algorithm such as the [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

Answer (score 1):

Your question text and question title point us in rather different directions.  Do you want to figure out:

- a triangulation from a set of points (Google for Delauny triangulation); or
- the polygon which encloses your set of points (convex hull) or
- whether a given lat,long pair is inside a country or not (point in polygon -- but this means that you have to have a polygonal representation of your country, and I guarantee that for some countries it won't be a nice convex polygon).

No, you shouldn't need a PhD to code this, they're all fairly well-documented problems in computational geometry.  You'll be able to find open source software for all of the above.  Your biggest problem is likely to be finding a polygonal representation of every country you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) or other .

Answer (score 0):

There's a library named qhull (http://www.qhull.org/) for doing this kind of job.  It's solid enough to use in Blender, OGRE3D, and other apps that get serious use, and has APIs for more then just C/C++.  It can even be used on the command line with simple text files of data for manual experimentation.

No need for a PhD, just a license to install  8D

There are others, but mostly of use to researchers or for special applications.